# What is the difference between Adapter and Repository pattern?

Tags: python, algorithm, design-patterns, repository-pattern

I'm kinda new to this "pattern" thing so I made up a repository to help me to consume and test an API in python. Then I showed it to a friend who said it wasn't a repository pattern but an adapter. Once he is an older and better programmer than me I can't argue against, also I have no clue what is the difference between both.

So, here is the code (I'm very proud about this one)

```py
# imports
from repository.utils import factory_getter
from typing import Union

# return objects containing lists of animes
class Animes(object):
    # get anime list for a given days of the week
    def get_day_schedule(self, day: str):
        return factory_getter("schedule", day)

    # return a object containing a list of animes airing in the current day
    def get_today_schedule(self):
        return factory_getter("schedule")

    # get anime list for a given year and season
    def get_early_season(self, season: Union[str, int], year: Union[str, int]):
        return factory_getter("season", str(season), str(year))

    # get animes airing in the current season
    def get_current_season(self):
        return factory_getter("season")

    # get animes that have been announced for the upcoming seasons
    def get_later_season(self):
        return factory_getter("season", "later")

    # get the best rated animes of the season
    def get_top_airing(self, page: Union[str, int] = 1):
        return factory_getter("top", "anime", str(page), "airing")

    # get the best rated movies
    def get_top_movies(self, page: Union[str, int] = 1):
        return factory_getter("top", "anime", str(page), "airing")

    # get animes of a certain genre
    def get_genre(self, genre, page: Union[str, int] = 1):
        return factory_getter("genre", "anime", str(genre), str(page))
```

That's it.
I would also be very grateful if you could direct me to some study material. Thanks

Comment: What Repository pattern did you think this example represented, and why?

Answer (score 0):

Well, Adapter pattern is used for the case where you have an old implementation and a new implementation for the same thing,  but their interfaces are different, i.e. the two impls aren't substituble but conceptually they're doing the same thing. Perhaps it might be the case that the new implementation would need to reuse most of the old implementation. If we substitute the old implementation with new, it would cause breaking changes. So what we do is, we extract out the interface of the old implementation. And use that interface wherever the old impl was being used, while we write our own impl of that "Adapter". The impl of adapter can reuse the old impl and can provide it's new behavior, but conforming now to a common interface.

Repository, well, is a completely different thing. It is used to to encapsulate all accesses to the entities and daos. What has adapter got to do with Repository? Is there a specific case?

One might need to write adapter for a repository, giving it additional functionality while still reusing it's old methods - it's very useful in Spring data where impls have out of the box behavior using dynamic proxies. Well, I don't know what your exact case is. But hope this helps.

Comment: We use Adapter pattern to enable interface segregation while providing our own impls of repositories and still using spring data's dynamic proxy support. We can't just extend or implement a CrudRepository,  otherwise we would have to define 10 20 methods, and then Spring data would be of disadvantage to us. So that's why we use Adapter pattern there.